# Responsive Webpage: Responsive navigation menu visible when closed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for my dad at the moment with some help of youtube tutorials. I came across some little problems.

I made a responsive navigation bar that wil open on the side on the screen, but when it's closed you can scroll all the way to the right of the screen and see the div element. The responsive navigation bar is made with HTML, CSS and JS. How can I get rid of this?

Another problem is that I recently made a image carousel. When I open this div from the responsive navigation bar, it will fade away together with my carousel. The carousel is entirely made with HTML and CSS. How can I get rid of this aswell?

I'm a first year student of ICT so I'm a big beginner (my english isn't great aswell). Could someone help me with my problems? And do I need to post some code with this question?

The website: https://verm0158.github.io/vermeerwebsite/ (desktop works fine, but mobile is a disaster)

Kind Regards,

Jan Vermeer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For the overflow issue, look into the CSS `overflow` attribute. It's good that you have provided a link to the web site, but you should also mention the library you're using to add the carousel, and add your code snippets for the JS and the HTML for all the issues you list. Also add tags for carousel library and any others.

Answer (score 0):

U have 3 columns on menu and u gave it's UL tag height of vh so it's children shown in whole height of it. u can add another div inside ul and give it lesser height that should solve your problem. or add more menu colums. but your colums gonna be seen as rows. so must be calculate well or use div before using li s or give li s padding top and bottom according your vh for making them responsive

Comment: In order to get proper assistance with this question, you should add code snippets for your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To keep showing the navLink even with the corousel, you must set the property `z-index: 1` to the `.navlinks`

```
.navlinks {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 125px;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;   
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;

    z-index: 1;
}
```

And the other thing, when you set a `position: absolute` in an element, you should set `position: relative` to its parent. If you don't do that, the absolute object will take reference on the next relative positioned container, in this case, the whole body. Try setting the position relative to the nav tag and on mobile screen set the body to `overflow:hidden`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The carousel problem is fixed now! But I'm stuck with a new problem now. I tried the other solution for the scroll issue. It worked, I can't scroll right anymore. But I can't scroll down either. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ups, my mistake... the property is ```` overflow-x : hidden ````The way I told you before, forbides the overflow in both directions. :)

Comment: I hate to say it, but when I do that I can scroll to the right again. I now know what you try to do with the solution but it doesn't seem to work. Very intresting. Anything else I can try?